# Selenium browser window size

Tags: php, unit-testing, firefox, selenium, laravel-5.1

I'm new at using selenium. I have downloaded the Selenium Standalone Server and successfully got it running by typing

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar
```

into the command line.

After running

```
 phpunit.bat
```

from the command line, all of my tests will pass as expected except for one unless I manually maximize the Firefox browser window that automatically is opened during the testing process.

While the tests are running, when the Firefox browser window opens, if I don't maximize that window while my login test is running, then that test will fail and somehow redirect to a unexpected page on my website. If I do maximize the window before the test completes, the "login" button gets clicked as expected, the correct page gets loaded, and the test passes.

Thus, I'm wondering if there is a way to change the settings somewhere so that the Firefox browser would just open maximized while the tests are running?

I've Googled around and discovered some various code snippets that might help, but I'm not sure where the PHP version of this code is or where to put some similar code for the version of Selenium I'm using (the Selenium Standalone Server):

```
# repositioning and resizing browser window:
driver.manage.window.move_to(300, 400)
driver.manage.window.resize_to(500, 800)
driver.manage.window.maximize
```

or this which is C#, but I need PHP and don't know where to find the right code or where to put it:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Here is the code for the login Selenium test in question (using Laracasts/Integrated) from my tests/SeleniumTest.php file:

```
<?php

use Laracasts\Integrated\Extensions\Selenium;
use Laracasts\Integrated\Services\Laravel\Application as Laravel;

class SeleniumTest extends Selenium
{
    use Laravel;
    /**
     * Tests to see if the login page loads
     */
    public function testToSeeIfLoginLoads()
    {
        $this->visit('/login')
            ->see('Login')->see('Email Address')->see('Password')
            ->type('myemail@email.com', 'email')->type('mypassword', 'password')
            ->waitForElement('log_in')
           ->click('log_in')
            ->waitForElement('table_summary')
            ->see('Complete Course Summary');
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you built you login test in a fragile manner such that location of the button within the window matters.  You should think about calling a click event on the DOM element rather than rely on a click a position X,Y.

Comment: @MikeBrant That's a logical solution that matches the problem, but I just updated my question above to include the login test that is failing.  As far as I can tell, the button should get clicked no matter where it is on the page since it's referenced by the id "log_in"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not using Laravel, I'm using classic phpunit + selenium RC and/or webdriver and this works for me on both implementations, right after opening the url, if I only want this for a specific test:

```php
$this->open("/");
$this->getEval("window.resizeTo(1225, 996); window.moveTo(0,200);");
//or $this->windowMaximize();
```

or for facebook-webdriver:

```php
$this->driver->get('myurl/');
$this->driver->manage()->window()->setSize(new WebDriverDimension(1225, 996));
```

If you want it for all tests, you should find the setUp method and put it there. In your case, for a specific test, [this should work](https://github.com/laracasts/Integrated/issues/120):

```php
$this
  ->visit('/')->session->window($this->session->window_handle())
  ->postSize(['height' => 996, 'width' => 1225]);
```

To import `WebDriverDimensions` add

```php
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension;
```

More info on usage, [here](https://github.com/laracasts/Integrated/wiki/Learn-the-API).

Comment: It might take me some time to look into this, but thanks for the answer.  It looks promising :)

Comment: What namespace is WebDriverDimension from?

Comment: `use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension;`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried overriding the setUpPage function?

```
public function setUpPage()
    {
         $this->currentWindow()->maximize();
    }
```

Comment: Putting that in tests/SeleniumTest.php doesn't do anything.  Maybe there is a different similar method though?

Comment: I think the problem with this solution is that it's not extending Laracasts/Integrated but probably something like Selenium2TestCase